# In Russia, what happens if there is only one candidate in an election?

Tags: election, russian-federation

[Russian cleaner sweeps to power in surprise village vote](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-54338785)

This story includes the following paragraph:

> When no-one in the village signed-up to challenge Nikolai Loktev, who's from the pro-Kremlin United Russia party, he persuaded Ms Udgodskaya to register as his "rival" to ensure the minimum requirement of two candidates.

What would have happened if Ms Udgodskaya had not registered as a candidate, and Nikolai Loktev was the only name on the ballot? The paragraph says there's a "minimum requirement" of two candidates, which would imply the election cannot go ahead - but if the election does not go ahead, who ends up as the administrator?

Comment: That journalist sure had fun coming up with that headline.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not too sure, but there's a [Russian source](https://www.rbc.ru/politics/02/10/2018/5bb3897c9a79476dca92a862) and [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_Khakassia_head_election) that explain this nicely.

Basically, if there is 1 candidate in the type of election you are talking about, an "Against All" column would be added to the ballot. The 1 candidate would need to win an absolute majority, otherwise a new election would be called in 3 months.

Direct quote from the Russian source (translated): "If all the candidates for the head of the region are removed, except for one, opposite the name of the only candidate there will be two boxes - "for"and "against all" and the candidate to win will have to gain more than 50% of the votes at any turnout"